# Cant do anything on my Htc one m8

Tags: boot-loop

My htc one m8 was all good since yesterday. It's age is about one year. The problem is when i open any apps or do anything it's just restart automatically and vanish my previous activity. As a example I uninstall an app then it restart and after restarting the is still there. I also try to factory reset the phone but it's done nothing all my apps was there.Can anyone help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem also happens into safe mode. I've tried both from settings menu and also recovery menu to factory reset the phone.

Comment: Which brand is it? Is it rooted?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your memory is read-only! You can't write data to it: the delete operation writes to memory - at least modifies it.

Not sure about what may be causing this, but probably from malwares or as I can think of now a defective eMMC chip like you know those SD Card that suddenly becomes "Write protection enabled" .

I have myself experienced this and never found a solution so far. This seems to happen with HTC, HUAWEI and I had a case involving a Motorola phone.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. Which memory you are telling about? Imternal or external

Comment: I am not able to change anything to my htc one m8. Every time I try to change something it takes reboots and goes to the same place where the problem starts. I have found others having this issue in this https://androidforums.com/threads/internal-phone-storage-becomes-read-only.347685/. Help me pls. I don't understand the instruction there.

Comment: I mean the internal memory. You may try flashing the firmware to the phone and see if it gonna solve this.